# Dynamically adjust ListView height on adding / removing items?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, windows-store-apps

I have a 3 Level Nested ListView binded to the same 3 Level Nested Collection. MainItems are added at the 3rd level.

Unmodified, there are scrollbars on **ALL** the levels. On item added, I edit the **Containing Grid** of the ListViewItem to adjust the height dynamically.

I have succeeded on **removing** the **3rd Level Scroll Bar**. However, I want to remove the **2nd Level** also, which I can't seem to do.

When I try to adjust the height of the **1st Level ListViewItem**, the **scrollbars on the 1st Level just disappears** but the height is not adjusted at all.

What I want to do is **ONLY** have the ScrollBar on the **1st Level** and scroll from there.

Basically, something like this:

[image: Remove the 2nd level scrollbar]

This is my current code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ParentGrid">
<ListView x:Name="Level1ListView" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Level1}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="GridLevel1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ToolKit_Controls:LayoutTransformControl Grid.Column="0">
                    <ToolKit_Controls:LayoutTransformControl.Transform>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" Angle="270"/>
                    </ToolKit_Controls:LayoutTransformControl.Transform>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Level1NameString}" FontSize="32" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </ToolKit_Controls:LayoutTransformControl>
                <ListView x:Name="Level2ListView"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Level2}"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid x:Name="GridLevel2">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text='{Binding Path=Level2Name}' Foreground="Black" FontSize="18"
                                       Grid.Row="0"/>

                                <Grid x:Name="GridLevel3" Width="300" Height="100" Grid.Row="1">
                                    <ListView x:Name="ListView_Level3" IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                                    ManipulationMode="None"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Level3DisplayCollection}"
                                                          Grid.Column="1">
                                        <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                            <TransitionCollection>
                                                <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
                                            </TransitionCollection>
                                        </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                    </ListView>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="1" ></WrapGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

And the important code which changes the height on item added:

```
var GridLevel1 = TypedAssociatedObject.GetAncestors().Where(a =>      a.Named("GridLevel1")).FirstOrDefault() as Grid;
//GridLevel1.Height = GridLevel1.ActualHeight + 50;

var GridLevel2 = TypedAssociatedObject.GetAncestors().Where(a => a.Named("GridLevel2")).FirstOrDefault() as Grid;
GridLevel2.Height = GridLevel2.ActualHeight + 50;

var GridLevel3 = TypedAssociatedObject.GetAncestors().Where(a => a.Named("GridLevel3")).FirstOrDefault() as Grid;
GridLevel3.Height = GridLevel3.ActualHeight + 50;
```

Level 1 is commented out because when I add it, although the **2nd Scroll Bar is removed** the ListViewItem height doesn't change, resulting in the UI being wrong and not showing everything. You also notice that the 1st level scrollbar remains the same size:

[image]

What I want is to **extend** the height of **Header 1** so that everything still shows and the **1st Level Scrollbar** on the right is the one that extends / grows.

Can anyone help point out what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Edit: This is a Windows store app.

Comment: Seems to me you'd be much  better off using a `TreeView` for this.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is a Windows store app. Unfortunately, treeview is not available i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ItemsPanel` to `StackPanel` in your inner list views. This way you would not need to adjust the height of each item.
Also to hide the scrollbars use `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" on your inner list views.`

Have you considered using [grouping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780627.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks Kristian! Removing the ItemsPanel WrapGrid fixed the issue with the 1st Level ScrollBar! I tried setting the ItemsPanel to StackPanel and removing the dynamic addition to height but it seems that doesn't work? I placed it on ALL the ListViews. What happens is, the height doesn't change and although the scrollbar doesn't show, I can still scroll to 'see' the other items.

Comment: I figured it out, the Height=100 or any static height will prevent StackPanel from auto-increasing in size.